# Centering Wordpress Sidebar Widgets

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I'm building a wordpress theme and i created 3 sidebars to use on footer. I need to have dynamic width of those 3 sidebars depending of how many of them are active.

So for example if I have only footer1 sidebar active, the width should be 100%

If I have footer1 and footer2, or footer1 and footer3, or footer2 and footer3 active they should be 50%,

And if I have all 3 of them active 33%.

Finally, the widgets are held in one sidebar, and not separate.

I'm not sure how to create the conditional statement, given that the 3 widgets are in one sidebar.

functions.php file

```
register_sidebar( array(
    'name' => __( 'First Footer', 'captiva' ),
    'id' => 'first-footer',
    'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 %2$s">',
    'after_widget' => '</div>',
    'before_title' => '<h4 class="widget-title">',
    'after_title' => '</h4>',
) );
```

footer.php file

```
<footer class="footercontainer" role="contentinfo"> 
    <?php if ( $cap_footer_top_active == 'yes' ) { ?>
        <?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'first-footer' ) ) : ?>
            <div class="lightwrapper">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'first-footer' ); ?>
                    </div><!-- /.row -->
                </div><!-- /.container -->
            </div><!-- /.lightwrapper -->
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php } ?>
```

Comment: please post your code

Comment: Whoever read the post and decided to down vote the question, I hope you at least know how I can solve the problem.  I have been trying for hours before I decided to post the question.

Comment: I think you got a downvote for your description... There are a number of things wrong with it, for a start you're only using one sidebar! With a dynamic number of widgets... blah blah. The code posted below will fix your problem though. Please up-vote if it helps.

Comment: fair enough. got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work...

```css
.row div {
 float: left;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
/* one item */
.row div:first-child:nth-last-child(1) {
width: 100%;
}
/* two items */
.row div:first-child:nth-last-child(2),
.row div:first-child:nth-last-child(2) ~ div {
width: 50%;
padding: 0 3.7%;
}
/* three items */
.row div:first-child:nth-last-child(3),
.row div:first-child:nth-last-child(3) ~ div {
width: 33.3%;
padding: 0 2.7%;
}
/* four items */
.row div:first-child:nth-last-child(4),
.row div:first-child:nth-last-child(4) ~ div,
/* Every item after the fourth will also use this width */
.row div:nth-last-child(n+5) {
width: 25%;
padding: 0 1.7%;
}
```

```html
<h2>Sidebar with 4 widgets</h2>
<div class="lightwrapper">
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
 <div> 
              <h4>WIDGET #1</h4>
              <P>You know, your bobby dangler, giggle stick...</P>
          </div>
 <div> 
              <h4>WIDGET #2</h4>
              <P>You know, your bobby dangler, giggle stick...</P>
          </div>
 <div> 
              <h4>WIDGET #3</h4>
              <P>You know, your bobby dangler, giggle stick...</P>
          </div>
 <div> 
              <h4>WIDGET #4</h4>
              <P>You know, your bobby dangler, giggle stick...</P>
          </div>
  </div><!-- /.row -->
 </div><!-- /.container -->
</div><!-- /.lightwrapper -->
          
          
<br style="clear: both">  
    
<h2>Sidebar with 2 widgets</h2>
<div class="lightwrapper">
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
 <div> 
              <h4>WIDGET #1</h4>
              <P>You know, your bobby dangler, giggle stick...</P>
          </div>
 <div> 
              <h4>WIDGET #2</h4>
              <P>You know, your bobby dangler, giggle stick...</P>
          </div>
  </div><!-- /.row -->
 </div><!-- /.container -->
</div><!-- /.lightwrapper -->
```

Comment: Click Run code script to see the result. You may need to add the .lightwrapper class to contain it to those widgets only. FYI

Comment: Thanks but how did you arrive at this answer? Based on the wordpress code above,  it checks for an active sidebar,  and displays it if it's active.

Comment: Your only using one sidebar from the code above. Which tells me you are trying to style the widgets contained in that sidebar. It also shows you're wrapping each widget in a div with a bunch of classes. So for me the code above is simplest way would be to get CSS to recognise the amount of divs (widgets) within the .row.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you a dynamic width:

```
    <?php
    function display_dynamic_sidebar($sidebar = array()) {
        if (function_exists('dynamic_sidebar')) {

            // Store all activated sidebars here
            $activated_sidebars = array();  

            // Loop through each sidebar
            foreach($sidebar as $value) {   
                if (is_active_sidebar($value)) {
                    // Push all activated sidebars to our array 
                    array_push($activated_sidebars, $value);                    
                }
            }

            // Define the width 
            switch (count($activated_sidebars)) {
                case 2:
                    $defined_width = '50%';
                    break;
                case 3:
                    $defined_width = '33%';
                    break;
                default:
                    $defined_width = '100%';


}

         // Finally tell jQuery to set a dynamic width
        echo '<script>$(".my-footer").css( "width", "'. $defined_width .'" );</script>';
    }
}

display_dynamic_sidebar(array('sidebar-1', 'sidebar-2', 'sidebar-3', 'sidebar-4'));
```

Just rename the css class (.my-footer) and the function parameters. Instead of 33%, 50% and 100% you could also use Bootstrap classes like col-md-12, col-md-6 and col-md-4.